# Overload plus `+` operator on String

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

In the following example, I'm trying to declare a class `WrappedString`, which simply wraps a `String` [1]. I'd like to be able to concatenate such instances with the `+` operator and have plain `String` instances automatically converted to `WrappedString` instances when necessary.

So there are three possible applications of the `+` operator which should return a `WrappedString` instance, illustrated with calls to `println()` at the bottom of the example.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object test extends App {
  case class WrappedString(value: String) {
    override def toString = s"[$value]"
    def +(right: WrappedString) = WrappedString(value + right.value)
  }

  object WrappedString {
    implicit def fromString(value: String) = WrappedString(value)
  }

  implicit class StringExtensions(value: String) {
    // Isn't actually used in the code below.
    def +(right: WrappedString) = WrappedString(value) + right
  }

  println(WrappedString("a") + WrappedString("b")) // [ab]
  println(WrappedString("a") + "b") // [ab]

  // Would like this to print `[ab]`
  println("a" + WrappedString("b")) // a[b]
}
```

For some reason, the 3rd example prints `a[b]`. The `WrappedString` instance is converted to a `String` before being concatenated with the string `"a"` to produce the final result.

How can I change the declarations of `WrappedString` and/or the implicits so that in the 3rd example, the `String` is converted to a `WrappedString` before the `+` operator is applied?

[1]: In the project I'm working on, the wrapped string carries formatting information in the form of [ANSI SGR escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will never choose an implicit `+` method over an explicit `+` method, which is something the `String` class has, so `"a" + WrappedString("b")` will always become `"a".+(WrappedString("b").toString)`.

To force the conversion you could pick a different method name, one that `String` doesn't have, along with an implicit class, which means it can't be a `case` class. That way you don't need the `implicitConversions` import, which is discouraged.

```
implicit class WrappedString(val value: String) {
  override def toString = s"[$value]"
  def +#(right: WrappedString) = WrappedString(value + right.value)
}

WrappedString("a") +# WrappedString("b") // [ab]
WrappedString("a") +# "b" // [ab]
"a" +# WrappedString("b") // [ab]
"a" +# "b" // also [ab]
```

It might also be helpful if you didn't use a class name that already exists in the Standard Library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I indeed switched to a different operator, which solved the problem. You state that `String` already has an explicit `+` method defined. Where is it defined?

Comment: @Feuermurmel it is defined there: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#+(x$1:Any):String

Comment: @stsatlantis That's `StringOps`, not `String`. The documentation says that `String` is implicitly converted to `StringOps`, if necessary. Where does it say that the `StringOps` conversion has higher precedence than everything else?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you are right it's defined on the `java.lang.String` which the scala `String` is assigned to. `type String        = java.lang.String` in the Predef

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering where you actually want the implicit conversion as you're manually wrapping all the values in `WrappedString` yourself. It seems you need something like a right-associative operator which Scala support using the `:` at the end of the function name.

For example:

```
case class WrappedString(value: String) {
    override def toString = s"[$value]"
    def +(right: WrappedString) = WrappedString(value + right.value)
    def +:(right: WrappedString) = right + WrappedString(value)
}

println("a" +: WrappedString("b")) // [ab]
```

Other than that you could force the conversion by specifying the type like:

```
println(("a": WrappedString) +: WrappedString("b")) // [ab]
```

Or possibly just move this to a separate function. Happy to be corrected but how else would the compiler ever know what your intention is as a `String` already has a valid `+` function and exploring all possible conversions wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand how [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) comes into play in these examples, neither the question nor you answer contains an example with more two `String` or `WrappedString` values being combined without parenthesis so associativity of the used operators don't matter.

Comment: You state that `String` already as a valid `+` function defined. Where is it defined?

Comment: Defined in a practical sense. If you look at Definitions.scala (syntheticCoreMethods) you can see that it's synthesized on-the-fly but that's about as much as I know. For `+:` the compiler will look at the right type (in your case `WrappedString`) first so knows how to prepend the `"a"` even though it's a `String`. Analogue to the same operator for `List`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the elaboration. I have not yet picked up that operators ending in a `:` are resolved on the _right_ operand instead of the _left_ one. It won't help in my case as I want to use the same operator whether the plan `String` is on the left or right.

Comment: @Feuermurmel `String` `+` defined on `java.lang.String` which the scala `String` is alias for.